# Delete a range of elements from a list

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

If I have a list of 100 integers, say `{1,2...100}`, and I wished to delete all elements that are greater than a random integer $n$, what command should I use for this?

For example if $n=5$, how do I operate the original list to get the final list of `{1,2,3,4,5}`?

Comment: Consider using Szabolcs' `BoolEval` package, available [here](https://github.com/szhorvat/BoolEval). One of the functions in the package are available [in the function repository](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/BoolEval), and it could be used with `Pick`. However, in the package itself there is a function called `BoolPick` which does exactly what you want with a very nice syntax.

Comment: You can use `Select` for this.  For example, `Select[Range[100], LessEqualThan[5]]`

Answer (score 7):

Are the elements sorted in order? If so:

```
n = RandomInteger[100];
list = Range[100];
list[[1;;n]]
```

Otherwise:

```
Select[list, # <= n &]
```

Answer (score 4):

It `lst` is sorted, maybe:

```
TakeWhile[lst, #<=5&]
```

Otherwise, maybe:

```
lst//Pick[#,Clip[# - 5, {0, \[Infinity]}],0]&
```

Or (thanks to [C.E](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/731/c-e)):

```
lst//Pick[#, UnitStep[5-#], 1]&
```

**Example**

```
 lst=RandomInteger[10,100];
 lst//Pick[#, UnitStep[5-#], 1]&
```

> {3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 2, 1, 4, 0, 4, 5, 2, 4, 1, 0, 2, 4, 3, 5, 3, 0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 4, 3, 4, 5, 1, 4, 0, 1, 5, 0, 0, 1, 2, 5, 1, 3, 3, 2, 4, 3}

Comment: The `UnitStep` function would perhaps be easier to read than this usage of `Clip`.